# How to avoid page refresh after button click event in asp.net/vb.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

In the following code when I click on my `Clear_Button` my `OnClick` event refreshes my page and I don't want that to happen. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="Clear_Button" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="bordered-orange roundCorners toRight toMiddle" Text="Clear" Width="18%" Theme="Metropolis">
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

My Event :

```
Protected Sub Clear_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Author.Items.Clear()

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your answers !

I managed to make it work thanks to the `<asp:updatepanel>` element which allows not to refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault(); will work

Comment: Where should I put this instruction?

Comment: Where You have defined the form submit event or onClick event

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use in frontend like javascript to clearing your data or refreshing your page without postback
> `<asp:Button ID="Clear_Button" runat="server" CssClass="bordered-orange roundCorners toRight toMiddle" Text="Clear" Width="18%" Theme="Metropolis" OnClientClick="return resetButtonClick();"Text="Reset" />`
> `<script type="text/javascript"> function resetButtonClick() { $("#<%= txt1.ClientID %>").val("");$("#<%= txt2.ClientID %>").val(""); return false;}</script>`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent refresh, you can use:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ...     OnClientClick="return false;" >
</dx:ASPxButton>
```